# Change image of button when pressed, make image of button not change when released

Tags: android, android-button

When I press the button image changes, but my problem is when I release the button, the image changes again (does not retain images). I am new to Java programming.

My layout :

```
 <Button
    android:background="@drawable/volume"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

And this is my XML in drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/volume_off" /> <!-- pressed -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/volume_on" /> <!-- default -->
```

Comment: I think maybe the things you really need is ToggleButton

Comment: it works,,,thanks to all,,,I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the image of your button permanently when you click it, it convenient to do it programmatically, inside the onClick void of your button.
For example if

image1: R.drawable.image_first
image2: R.drawable.image_second

and in your XML layout file you have:

```
 <Button
    android:background="@drawable/volume"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="click"/>
```

in the Activity you can do:

```
public Class myActivity extends Activity{

Button mButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myactivity_layout);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

public void click(View v){
   mButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_second);
}

}
```

If you want to come back to the previous image after clicking again, just save the state of your button (boolean clicked = true/false) and put an if statement inside the public void click.

Comment: yess,,it works,,,but like you said, to come back in previous image i should inside if statement,,,i confuse how to inside if statement in public void, if in bascom  avr and arduino IDE, i can understand easely but in java i really don't understand,,,would you give example codes if statement in public void ...thanks before,

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you want to change your volume indicator, I think you should do programmatically like this.

```
  //At the top of your activity,declare a global variable
  boolean isVolumeOn = true;

  volumeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //check your volume status
                    if(isVolumeOn){
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_off);
                        isVolumeOn = false;
                        //Turn off your volume here

                    }else{
                        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_on);
                        isVolumeOn = true
                        //Turn on your volume here

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: thanks QuangNguyen to respons my question, i don't understand with "isVolumeOn". what is that mean?
may you give me more clearly example program, Sorry i'm new here..

Comment: are you adding the feature that users can turn on or off volume in your application?

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove default image from selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/volume_off" /> <!-- pressed -->
</selector>
```

remove this line  `<!--<item android:drawable="@drawable/volume_on" /> remove default-->`

it is set default when button state is changed.

```
<Button
android:background="@drawable/volume"
android:layout_width="90dp"
android:layout_height="90dp"
android:src="@drawable/volume_on"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: if i remove that line, so the button be invisible, the button be visible (show Volume_off) when i press the button,

Answer (score 0):

in my content_main.xml

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/volume_on"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="click" />
```

in my MainActivity.java

```
public Class myActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
```

Button volume;
   boolean isPressed=false;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myactivity_layout);
    volume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

public void click(View v){
if (isPressed) {
    volume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_off);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Off",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    volume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.volume_on);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Volume On",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
    isPressed=!isPressed;
}
```